# Bonding NICs with Procurve 1400-24G switch

Tags: switch, nic, bonding, hp-procurve

I was looking to bond two or three NICs together to increase throughput. Now, this should be straight forward if done computer to computer, but since there are 3 computers involved which require higher bandwidth, I was going to put them into a a HP Procurve 1400-24G switch.

Since I'm not sure how switches work, I wasn't sure whether being a gigabit switch it should be capable of switching 3gbit of data between 2 computers or whether there would be some feature that would limit the effective transfer between 2 computers to only 1gbit regardless of the bonding.

Can somebody please confirm? Thanks.

Comment: If you are only connecting two computers bonding may not be very useful.  Many bonding implementations hash by IP.  Meaning that between two computers you will only get the throughput of a single connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It looks like this switch doesn't support link aggregation so only way of bonding is to use round robin, which I suspect will not work very well. Looks like I need a new switch...